# Hibernate Search with Elasticsearch creating fields with .keyword suffix

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search, elasticsearch-5

I just implemented the integration of Hibernate Search with Elasticsearch using hibernate search 5.8 and ES 5.5.
I have several fields created specifically for sorting, and they are all called [field]Sort.

When I was testing it locally, the first time I let Hibernate create the indexes, it created the String sort fields like this:

```
nameSort -> text
nameSort.keyword -> keyword
```

I realized that I should use the suffixed field for sorting.
But then, when I destroyed my Elasticsearch cluster, to start over, it didn't create the suffixed fields, it just created the sort fields as keyword directly.
I recreated the cluster 5 or more times again and it never created the suffixed fields again.

When I finally sent my changes to our staging environment, it created the suffixed fields again, causing my queries to fail, because they are trying to sort by a text field, instead of a keyword field.

Now, I'm really not sure of why it sometimes creates the suffix and sometimes doesn't.
Is there any rule?
Is there a way to avoid it creating 2 fields and making it always create only one keyword field with exactly the name I gave it?

Here's an example of a sort field:

```
@Field(name = "nameSort", analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, index = Index.NO)
@SortableField(forField = "nameSort")
public String getNameSort() {
    return name != null ? name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) : null;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Search does no such thing as creating a separate keyword field for text fields. It creates either a text field or a keyword field, depending on whether the field should be analyzed. In your case, the field is not analyzed, so it should create a keyword field.

Now, Hibernate Search is not alone here, and this behavior could stem from the Elasticsearch cluster itself. Did you check whether you have particular index templates on your Elasticsearch cluster? It could lead to Elasticsearch creating a keyword field whenever Hibernate Search creates a text property.

On a side note, you may be interested by the fact Hibernate Search 5.8 allows defining normalizers (same thing as Elasticsearch normalizers), which would allow you to annotate the getName() getter directly and avoid doing the lowercase conversion yourself. See [this blog post](http://in.relation.to/2017/06/13/hibernate-search-5-8-0-Beta3/#normalizers) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
I'm going to check our ES cluster to see if it has any configuration on fields creation.
The strangest part for me is that it actually created a field of type text for this non analyzed field that is supposed to be a keyword field already..

Comment: @andrehil it seems you are running into the same issues we are with using hibernate search. I have to ask again, did you find a way to solve this issue? For us, this issue is ONLY caused when hitting the ES cluster with a DELETE rest call, and THEN running the MassIndexer, strangely enough.

Just running the mass indexer alone results in normal behavior.

Comment: @logeyg Are you talking about a call to the "delete index" API? The only way I could see this work is that you somehow allowed implicit index creation and your Elasticsearch index and mapping get created automatically on the first indexed document being indexed. In that case the schema will be inferred from that first document, and is very likely to be just plain wrong. Maybe avoid deleting the index, and just delete documents instead? The mass indexer allows that via the `purgeAllOnStart` option.

Comment: @YoannRodière thanks for the answer. that was indeed what was happening. The issue is, in a production environment, we will need to delete the index at some point - for example, if a mapping changes dramatically. It seems like the mass indexer does not support something like this?

Comment: @logeyg No it does not (yet), so you'll have to stop your application, delete the index using Elasticsearch APIs, restart the application, and then reindex. Or write an [Elasticsearch reindex script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html) (just like you would do if your database schema changed) if you think it's feasible, but it'll likely be a lot more work and may be complex. I'd recommend the first solution.